Pamac cannot resolve alsa dependencies
I've just switched from the Stable branch of Manjaro to Testing and when doing sudo pamac upgrade, I get this error message and have no idea what to do:
Preparing... 
Synchronizing package databases...
Resolving dependencies...                                                                                     
Warning: cannot resolve "alsa-lib=1.2.12", a dependency of "lib32-alsa-lib"
Warning: cannot resolve "alsa-plugins=1:1.2.12", a dependency of "lib32-alsa-plugins"
Warning: cannot resolve "alsa-lib=1.2.12", a dependency of "lib32-alsa-lib"
Warning: cannot resolve "alsa-lib=1.2.12", a dependency of "lib32-alsa-lib"
Error: Failed to prepare transaction:
could not satisfy dependencies:
- unable to satisfy dependency 'alsa-lib=1.2.12' required by lib32-alsa-lib
- unable to satisfy dependency 'alsa-plugins=1:1.2.12' required by lib32-alsa-plugins


You should sync the mirrors after switching branches:
sudo pacman-mirrors --fasttrack && sudo pacman -Syyuu 

With sudo pacman -Syyuu instead of sudo pacman -Syu to force update. It helped me.

I did try syncing the mirrors, but it didn't seem to help. It still couldn't resolve the dependencies. I didn't try sudo pacman -Syyuu on the other hand, so that might have helped, but in the end I just reinstalled my entire system (also to fix a problem I had with nvidia graphics drivers).
